# How to see if a TextBox.Text is one of the words in text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to see if a textbox text is one of the words in an downloaded .txt file.

The only thing I know is that I can use
`if (words.Contains(txtBox.Text)`, but it will find any letter in the text file and act like the word is in the file.

```cs
        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string accessKeys;

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            accessKeys = wc.DownloadString("http://LinkToTextFile.txt");
            if (txtBxAccessKey.Text.Contains(" ") || txtBxAccessKey.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty");
            }
            else if (accessKeys.Contains(txtBxAccessKey.Text)) //This is what I need to change to work as intended
            {
                this.Hide();
                Loader frmLoader = new Loader();
                frmLoader.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access Key Not Found");
            }
```

Comment: Show some examples on wrong behaviour you described: "but it will find any letter in the text file and act like the word is in the file"

Comment: @RistoM In the text file I have the words 'admin' and 'test' on different lines, if I type the letter 'a' in the text box then it will continue to load 'frmLoader'

Comment: @RistoM The value is empty until somebody enters a value, in this case I type the letter 'a' and it continues to show 'frmLoader' because the text file has a word that contains the letter 'a'

Comment: Ok I see the problem. I can propose you some solution as an answer in few minutes..

Comment: @RistoM Okay, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution, where comparison is done against whole word in file (separated by whitespace).

1. Download file data as string
2. Split string to array of strings, separated by any whitespace (space, newline, tab)
3. Check if txtBxAccessKey.Text is one of the array items

Please check few notes I made as code comments (proper error handling, case-insensitive comparison). I also corrected you empty string comparison as more elegant. This snippet uses `Contains`-method found in `System.Linq`-namespace.

```
using System.Linq;

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    var fileContents = wc.DownloadString("http://LinkToTextFile.txt");
    //Todo 1: Error handling, check for empty!
    //Todo 2: Handle case in-sensitive comparison!
    string[] lines = fileContents.Split(null);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBxAccessKey.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty");
        return;
    }
    else if (lines.Contains(txtBxAccessKey.Text))
    {
        this.Hide();
        Loader frmLoader = new Loader();
        frmLoader.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Access Key Not Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: One last problem, if i wanted to ignore certain parts of the text file, how would that be done, I have tried adding //TEXTHERE, but it does not ignore it

This is the link I am using: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AnonXCSGO/YawnCheatsLoader/master/accesskeys.txt

Comment: It is easiest if you manipulate your string array on separate algorithm before making comparison. Try to make algorithm for that and make another SO question if there is some problem which arise on that. btw, I edited my answer slightly (now array contains all words in file, not only whole lines). Mark answer as accepted if your initial question is now answered.